# Basic audio denoising in the frequency domain using minimum statistics?

Tags: filters, fourier-transform, snr, denoising, wiener-filter

I'm trying to do some example elementary denoising of the audio signal. Let's say input is speech with constant traffic background noise.

- First I calculated block-based overlap-add Fourier transform (size 512) and continued in the frequency domain with the signal `in[n]`.
- Then I used minimum statistics method to estimate the noise in the frequency domain `noise[n]`.
- Lastly I calculated the `gain[n]` as signal-to-noise ratio `in[n]/noise[n]`.

Now that I have `gain[n]`, how should I continue in order to filter the signal and go back to the time domain?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have calculated the gain function in the frequency domain, you can apply it to your noisy signal to obtain a denoised signal. The steps you should follow are:

1- Multiply the noisy signal's Fourier transform by the gain function in the frequency domain. This gives you the processed Fourier coefficients.

2- Take the inverse Fourier transform of the processed Fourier coefficients. This gives you the denoised signal in the time domain.

3- In order to avoid artifacts at the beginning and end of the signal, you should overlap-add the denoised segments using a window function.